# QGIS terminates on importing opencv in python

Tags: python, qgis

My QGIS software terminates if I run "import cv2" in python console. The QGIS version is 3.6 Noosa.

Comment: I think you need to install the OPENCV module using pip in QGIS Terminal

Comment: I tried, but it still crashes.

Comment: In the OSGeo4W Shell run this command `pip list` and see if the module is installed or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue with Python `3.7.3`, QGIS `3.8.2`, OpenCV `4.1.0.25`, and Ubuntu `19.04`. When attempting to `import cv2` QGIS freezes, then silently exits. I tested the import with my system level interpreter, (the same one QGIS uses), and it worked fine.

My solution was to uninstall OpenCV:

`python3 -m pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python`

Then to install headless OpenCV:

`python3 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless`

The cost of this solution is the loss of `cv2.imshow()` and other GUI functionality. One can simply output to a file, if needed, to inspect results.

The [information here](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python#installation-and-usage) explains a bit more about the headless install and mentions that it is "suitable for more restricted environments."